# build fails when a class in a referenced library is extended

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, build

Good day

I am using maven to build my java project. I've added a log4j jar as a dependency and tried to `extend` its `RollingFileAppender` class. I tried to build it again and surprisingly an error occured. Is extending class from referenced libraries/jars forbidden?

Below is the said maven error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
c:\Users\jlim\Desktop\workspace\test-joven\src\main\java\com\joven\test\CustomRollingFileAppender.java:[3,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] c:\Users\jlim\Desktop\workspace\test-joven\src\main\java\com\joven\test\CustomRollingFileAppender.java:[5,47] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.045s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 20 15:56:14 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project test-joven: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[ERROR] c:\Users\jlim\Desktop\workspace\test-joven\src\main\java\com\joven\test\CustomRollingFileAppender.java:[3,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] c:\Users\jlim\Desktop\workspace\test-joven\src\main\java\com\joven\test\CustomRollingFileAppender.java:[5,47] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Below is the dependency block of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your pom file, cause i assume you added the dependency with scope test.

Comment: ok wait a moment i will edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of log4j is `runtime`:

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

So it's available only at runtime, and not at compilation time. Change it to `compile` (or remove it, since compile is the default)